# I want to display in a table an array with nested array

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my database;

```
[{
  "firstName": "Shaun",
  "salary": [
    {
    "id":1,
    "rate": 250,
    },
    {
    "id":2,
     "rate": 290,
    }
  ]
},{
  "firstName": "Julian",
  "salary": [
    {
    "id":1,
     "rate": 750,      
    },
    {
    "id":2,
     "rate": 760,      
    },
    {
    "id":3,
     "rate": 790,      
    },
  ]
}
}]
```

**HTML I have tried:-**

```
<table class="table" >
   <thead class="thead-light" >
      <tr *ngFor='let nameInfo of cleanReport; let i = index'>
         <th scope="col">{{nameInfo.firstName}}</th>
         <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody >
      <tr *ngFor='let info of nameInfo[i].salary'>
         <td>{{info.id}}</td>
         <td>{{info.rate}}</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

My desired result is a table that displays the name with corresponding occurrences of salary which is in a nested array. The table would be similar to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbseT.png)

Comment: What have you tried? It would help other contributor to help you.

Comment: this is what I have tried:
<table class="table" >
  <thead class="thead-light" >
    <tr *ngFor='let nameInfo of cleanReport; let i = index'>
      <th scope="col">{{nameInfo.firstName}}</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody >
       <tr *ngFor='let info of nameInfo[i].salary'>
      <td>{{info.id}}</td>
      <td>{{info.rate}}</td>
    </tr>   
  </tbody>  
</table>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one in your controller class:

```
 data: any;
ngOnInit() {
this.httpClient.get('assets/data.json').subscribe(data => {
  console.log(data);
  this.data = data;  
});
```

and this one in html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody *ngFor="let emp of data">
    <tr><td colspan="2" style="background-color: black;color: white;"> 
         {{emp.firstName}}</td></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>id</td>
          <td>rate</td>
        </tr>
        <tr  *ngFor="let sal of emp.salary">
        <td> {{sal.id}}</td>
        <td> {{sal.rate}}</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you for the CSS too.

Answer (score 0):

**Use nested `*ngFor` like this:-**

```
 <table class="table" >
       <thead class="thead-light" >
          <tr *ngFor='let nameInfo of cleanReport; let i = index'>
             <th scope="col">{{nameInfo.firstName}}</th>
             <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody >
          <ng-container *ngFor='let cr of cleanReport;'>
            <tr *ngFor='let salary of cr.salary;'>
              <td>{{salary.id}}</td>
              <td>{{salary.rate}}</td>
            </tr>
          </ng-container>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Somehow, I am unable to make this work on my machine. I am able to display the firstName but not the id and the rate. What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The solution you are looking for is in Angular's official tutorial. In this tutorial Phones are loaded from a JSON file using Angulars $http service . In the code below we use $http.get to load a phones.json file saved in the phones directory:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);   
phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('phones/phones.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.phones = data;
}); 
$scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

We then iterate over the phones:

```
<table>
  <tbody ng-repeat="i in phones">
    <tr><td>{{i.name}}</td><td>{{$index}}</td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="e in i.details">
       <td>{{$index}}</td>
       <td>{{e.foo}}</td>
       <td>{{e.bar}}</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, the solution above seems too complicated for me. Would you mind sending me the link from angular's official tutorial? appreciate it

Comment: thanks but it seems to me that this is not applicable in this case. I am using Angular 8 and not AngularJS